# iOS 7 custom separator does not mimic default separator behavior.

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to draw a custom separator in my custom `UITableViewCell`.

```
CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 1.0f);
border.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
[self.layer addSublayer:border];
```

My custom `UITableViewCell` height is `60`.

For some reason, when I scroll to the bottom of my table view, all the separators appears normally, but as I scroll back up the table, the table cells at the top do not show my separator.

I can potentially set my separator with `y` of `59`:

```
CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 59, 320, 1.0f);
border.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
[self.layer addSublayer:border];
```

But this behavior is not desired because when I select a row, I want the separator on the previous cell to disappear, this only happens when `y` is `60`, which is the height of my cell.

Answer (score 0):

If your cell height is 60pts, then setting the y position of a UIView to 60pts and 1pt heigh is going to draw it outside of the bounds of the cell.

This might work initially because of the order the cells are added to the tableView.. I.e The top cell is added after the second cell down so the 1pt separator as been drawn on top of the second cell... However when you scroll back up, the cells are added back to the tableView in a different order causing the separator to be hidden as the cell below it is drawn on top.

To get around this, you have to draw the separator inside the bounds of the cell.

I don't really understand why you want the separator on the previous cell (i presume you mean the last selected cell) to disappear but could you achieve this by overriding `setHighlighted:animated:` and `setSelected:animated:` on a custom UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: I don't want the last selected cell's separator to disappear, I want the cell that is directly above my current selected cell's separator to disappear. It's similar to the default separator, where when you select a cell, you do not see the separator from the cell above it.

Comment: Hmm, in that case.. How about manually drawing the separators over the top of the tableView? It's just a thought.. Not sure if it would be practical or not though but you would have easier control over their appearance etc

Comment: That seems alot harder to handle, I was thinking there might be a simpler solution.